# Why do I get easy_install error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'"?

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm trying to run the command:

```
easy_install MySQLdb
```

But, I'm getting the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

I'm using Windows 7 x64 with Python 2.6 x86 (I've tried Python x64, but I get the same error). I'm also using setuptools 0.6c11 (only available in 32-bit).

Please see the [full error on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/f4314d723).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to only be an egg for Python 2.5 on Windows. Try with Python 2.5 on Windows for now, and it should work, yet I agree having two versions of Python can really put you in a horrible situation sometimes. Also, the package is `MySQL-python` and not `MySQLdb`.

See [this other answered SU question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685869/mysqldb-on-python-2-6) for a workaround to get it on Python 2.6

Answer (score 1):

The package is called `MySQL-python`. Before barfing up the Traceback, python output:

```
Creating /Users/fideli/py2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/site.py
Searching for MySQLdb
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQLdb/
Couldn't find index page for 'MySQLdb' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for MySQLdb
Best match: None
```

Try `easy_install MySQL-python` instead.

Comment: I get the error, "error: The system cannot find the file specified". http://pastebin.com/f676f67ae

Comment: Ack, that's the limit of my help here. I don't use Python on Windows and I don't use MySQL at all. You can either edit this question with your new error and I'll delete this answer, or you can post a new question for that. Sorry!

Comment: Wait, your question is valid - just update it with "you need Python 2.5".

Answer (score 0):

Ah, looks like the error is caused because MySQLdb does not exist. They need a better error message I think. Furthermore, to use `setup.py install` on windows, we need to install the "Developer Components" during the MySQL server setup, and I think we must use MySQL 5.0 but I'm not sure.